# How to format all entries in string with single input?

Tags: python, string, format

I have data with nomenclature

```
teststr = {field1}_{field2}_test.txt
```

Where the first two fields normally represent different attributes. But in the vase there I would like to use `glob.glob` to search for all similar files, I would like to fill in all the entries with `*`. But `str.format` requires you to state explicitly one argument for each field. For a varying number of fields in the data nomenclature, I am looking for a function that can fill in every field in the string with a single input string.

I have tried

```
import re
teststr = re.sub('{.*}', '*', teststr)

>>> print(teststr)
*_test.txt
```

But the regex would search for the last curly brace.

Comment: Make your regex non-greedy by putting a `?` after `*`. `re.sub('{.*?}', '*', teststr)`

Comment: Awesome, this worked, but what does `?` do?

Comment: The keywords are in my comment: "non-greedy regex". You should have know what to do with these keywords :)